# Do we need to create iOS Universal Frameworks for CocoaPods and Carthage?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage, xcframework, ios-universal-framework

1. Is my understanding correct, that we need to manually create `Universal Frameworks/Libraries` only if we distribute our libs by providing binaries (let's say directly download `.framework`)? So if we distribute using CocoaPods or Carthage, these tools will create `Universal Frameworks/Libraries` from our source code by themselves, right?
2. As I understand, CocoaPods & Carthage allow to hide source code by distributing only binaries.
   Does that mean that in this case we need to create `Universal Frameworks/Libraries` by ourselves before using these services?
3. What's the best way to create `Universal Frameworks/Libraries` in 2020,  `XCFramework`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check this repo for your 3rd question: https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic. Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you distribute your source code with CocoaPods or Carthage, these systems will make your source code compiling either into `.framework` or into static library on the consumer side while the consumer’s project builds. Consumers will have access to your source code.
2. Yes.
3. If your framework is intended to be used in Mac Catalyst apps - then XCFramework is the only choice. Otherwise, you can still ship fat framework - old, but gold.

UPDATE:

With AppleSilicon, XCFramework becomes the only format in which you should ship your  prebuilt framework, because even iOS simulator now should support both `x86_64` and `arm64` architectures.